# Написание числительных

Tags: числительные

Как правильно написать данную часть предложения: "допускает 7-8 кратную перегрузку"?

Answer (score 1):

Цифры никогда не пишутся через дефис, разве что в номерах телефонов и тому  подобных *технических* случаях.

Тире между цифрами пишется без пробелов:

***...допускает 7–8-кратную перегрузку.***